# How to improve a control statement for text fields in Swift / Xcode iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm setting up a new application for iPhone and I want to add users input information into my database only if the text field is not empty.

There are 4 text fields but just one has to be complete to update my database.

Swift and iOS coding are new to me.

Here the code I want to improve:

```
@IBAction func confirmButtonWasPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Redirection to confirmation screen.")
    if confirmpasswordTextField.text != "" {
        print("Updating informations.")

        // Read values from text fields
        let userName = newusernameTextField.text
        let userMail = newmailTextField.text
        let userPhone = newphoneTextField.text
        let userPassword = newpasswordTextField.text

        if userName?.isEmpty ?? true {
            print("textField is empty")
        } else {
            print("textField has some text")
        }

        if userMail?.isEmpty ?? true {
            print("textField is empty")
        } else {
            print("textField has some text")
        }

        if userPhone?.isEmpty ?? true {
            print("textField is empty")
        } else {
            print("textField has some text")
        }

        if userPassword?.isEmpty ?? true {
            print("textField is empty")
        } else {
            print("textField has some text")
        }

    }else{
        print("Error: Please enter your password.")
    }
}
```

I want to reduce this function and get input if there have some.

I can do it with this code but I believe there has a short way to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: What is `confirmButtonWasPressed` supposed to do? Just print a few lines of text? What do you want to happen if one of the text fields is empty? Not do anything? What if all of them are non-empty?

Comment: Hello @Sweeper "confirmButtonWasPressed" confirm the update when the password is OK. If one of the text fields is empty do nothing for it. Only deal with the text fields where have input. If all of them are non-empty it's OK. It's for updating data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {
public var isBlank: Bool {
        let trimmed = trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        return trimmed.isEmpty
    }
}

@IBAction func confirmButtonWasPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
validateLogin() 
}

func validateLogin(){
guard let username = userNameTextfield.text, !username.isBlank else {
            return
        }
        guard let password = passwordTextField.text, !password.isBlank else {
            return
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the delegate and a small rewrite for the UITextField so you have the name it has in the Database. In whichever controller you are just do:

```
class TextField: UITextField {
    var nameInDataBase: String
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var newusernameTextField: TextField!
    @IBOutlet var newmailTextField: TextField!
    @IBOutlet var newphoneTextField: TextField!
    @IBOutlet var newpasswordTextField: TextField!

    func viewDidLoad(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        [newusernameTextField, newmailTextField, newphoneTextField, newpasswordTextField].forEach { $0.delegate = self }
        newusernameTextField.nameInDataBase = "newUserName"
        newmailTextField.nameInDataBase = "newMail"
        /// etc.
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        guard 
           let enteredText = textField.text, 
           let field = textField as? TextField 
        else {
            print ("nothing added or not TextField field")
        }

        logInDataBase(field.nameInDataBase, enteredText)
    }
```

If you need more info to log stuff in the database, it is just a matter of adding that info as variables of the child class of `UITextField`

Comment: Hello, @regina_fallangi thank you for your answer but can you explain to me those lines: `newusernameTextField.nameInDataBase = "newUserName"` `newmailTextField.nameInDataBase = "newMail"`

Comment: I created a child class `TextField` that inherits from `UITextField`. The child class has an instance variable called `nameInDataBase`. I don't know how you do the logging in the database, maybe you use a key, or a name, or a URL Post request...whatever info you use to distinguish each textfield's info, you can add that info to each textfield as instance variables and just use the info to do the logging without need to do `if textField == newusernameTextField else if textField == xxx {} else if {} else {}`.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll be back after a couple of tests. Thanks.

Comment: You mentioned in the edit that you need to log when just one is complete. You can just check `if textFieldThatHasToBeComplete == textField { log(xxx) }`. If you need any help, let me know.